# How do I create a pandas dataframe out of complex dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with keys of type tuple and values of type list. for example:

```
myDictionary= {('1', '1', '1', '1', '1'): [16.0, 75, 0.15, -99.0],
('1', '1', '1', '1', '2'): [16.0, 75, 0.15, -99.0],
('1', '1', '1', '2', '1'): [16.0, 75, 0.15, -99.0],
('1', '1', '1', '2', '2'): [16.0, 75, 0.15, -99.0],
('1', '1', '2', '1', '1'): [16.0, 75, 0.15, -99.0]
}
```

I would like to convert the above dictionary to pandas dataframe and add the header names for the indexes and values. The final table should look like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=None
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(myDictionary.items()):
    if df is None:
        df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'id{k+1}' for k in range(len(k))]+[f'val{k+1}' for k in range(len(v))])
    df.loc[i]=list(k)+v
```